# setlocale in NDK seems not to work for my language (Vietnamese)

Tags: c

My language is VietNam. I use NDK for run my code C in Android but some functions that use `wchar_t` do not work correctly. I think function `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");` does not work or does not work correctly for my language when using NDK.

Code example:

```
void synthesis_main(){
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ANDROID_LOG_INFO ", "TEST %ls",L"Tôi rất vui nếu chạy được.");
}
```

Result:

- have only character "T"

My question:

- How do I make setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "") work with NDK?
- Is there a regex library can use for characters in Japan or VietNam which use type of character is `char` (not `wchar_t`)?

Comment: There are multiple issues that will need to be addressed.  How have you set the default locale to Vietnamese?  Does the environment have locale support for Vietnamese?  Are you using the appropriate code set (UTF-8, or perhaps UTF-16 or even UTF-32 if you're using `wchar_t`)? Regarding the regexes, you'd have to define a multibyte code set to support the full range of characters; there isn't an 8-bit code set that can support the full diversity of Vietnamese, is there?

Comment: Can you also tell us what return `setlocale` in your case?